# How to read from embedded-kafka with fs2-kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, fs2, cats-effect, embedded-kafka

I am using [fs2-kafka](https://github.com/fd4s/fs2-kafka) to read from [embedded-kafka](https://github.com/embeddedkafka/embedded-kafka).

I create the embedded kafka using `withRunningKafkaOnFoundPort`, create topic and publish a few messages. However when I try to read it back with fs2-kafka I get a NullPointerException. I have isolated a test case and the code is below.

Here is my code:

```
import cats.effect._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect.implicits._
import fs2.Stream
import fs2.kafka.{AutoOffsetReset, ConsumerSettings, KafkaConsumer, consumerStream}
import net.manub.embeddedkafka.{EmbeddedKafka, EmbeddedKafkaConfig}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class KafkaSuite extends FunSuite with EmbeddedKafka {

  val singleThreadExecutor = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor((task: Runnable) => task.run())
  implicit val contextShift = IO.contextShift(singleThreadExecutor)
  implicit val timer = IO.timer(singleThreadExecutor)

  val topic = "example"
  val partition = 0
  val clientId = "client"

  test("works") {
    val userDefinedConfig = EmbeddedKafkaConfig(kafkaPort = 0, zooKeeperPort = 0)

    withRunningKafkaOnFoundPort(userDefinedConfig) { implicit actualConfig =>
      createCustomTopic(topic)
      publishStringMessageToKafka(topic, "example-message1")
      publishStringMessageToKafka(topic, "example-message2")
      publishStringMessageToKafka(topic, "example-message3")
      publishStringMessageToKafka(topic, "example-message4")

      val broker = s"localhost:${actualConfig.kafkaPort}"

      val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings[IO, String, String]
        .withAutoOffsetReset(AutoOffsetReset.Earliest)
        .withBootstrapServers(broker)
        .withGroupId("group")
        .withClientId(clientId)

      val r = consumerStream[IO].using(consumerSettings)
        .evalTap(_.subscribeTo(topic))
        .evalTap(_.seekToBeginning)
        .flatMap { consumer =>
          consumer.stream.take(1)
        }
        .compile
        .toList

      val res = r.unsafeRunSync()
      Console.println(res)
      assert(res.size == 1)
    }
  }

}
```

`build.sbt`:

```
name := "test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.12" % "3.1.2" % "test",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.25",
  "com.github.fd4s" %% "fs2-kafka" % "1.0.0",
  "io.github.embeddedkafka" %% "embedded-kafka" % "2.4.1.1" % Test
)
```

An here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:515)
    at fs2.kafka.Deserializer$.$anonfun$string$1(Deserializer.scala:208)
    at fs2.kafka.Deserializer$.$anonfun$lift$1(Deserializer.scala:184)
    at fs2.kafka.Deserializer$$anon$1.deserialize(Deserializer.scala:133)
    at fs2.kafka.ConsumerRecord$.deserializeFromBytes(ConsumerRecord.scala:166)
    at fs2.kafka.ConsumerRecord$.fromJava(ConsumerRecord.scala:177)
    at fs2.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.$anonfun$records$2(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:378)
    at cats.data.NonEmptyVectorInstances$$anon$1.traverse(NonEmptyVector.scala:300)
    at cats.data.NonEmptyVectorInstances$$anon$1.traverse(NonEmptyVector.scala:245)
    at cats.Traverse$Ops.traverse(Traverse.scala:19)
    at cats.Traverse$Ops.traverse$(Traverse.scala:19)
    at cats.Traverse$ToTraverseOps$$anon$2.traverse(Traverse.scala:19)
    at fs2.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.$anonfun$records$1(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:376)
    at cats.instances.VectorInstances$$anon$1.$anonfun$traverse$2(vector.scala:80)
    at cats.instances.VectorInstances$$anon$1.loop$2(vector.scala:43)
    at cats.instances.VectorInstances$$anon$1.$anonfun$foldRight$2(vector.scala:44)
    at cats.Eval$.advance(Eval.scala:271)
    at cats.Eval$.loop$1(Eval.scala:350)
    at cats.Eval$.cats$Eval$$evaluate(Eval.scala:368)
    at cats.Eval$Defer.value(Eval.scala:257)
    at cats.instances.VectorInstances$$anon$1.traverse(vector.scala:79)
    at cats.instances.VectorInstances$$anon$1.traverse(vector.scala:15)
    at cats.Traverse$Ops.traverse(Traverse.scala:19)
    at cats.Traverse$Ops.traverse$(Traverse.scala:19)
    at cats.Traverse$ToTraverseOps$$anon$2.traverse(Traverse.scala:19)
    at fs2.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.records(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:373)
    at fs2.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.$anonfun$poll$2(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:405)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.liftedTree1$1(IORunLoop.scala:95)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:95)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.startCancelable(IORunLoop.scala:41)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.run(IOBracket.scala:86)
    at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.cats$effect$internals$Trampoline$$immediateLoop(Trampoline.scala:70)
    at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.startLoop(Trampoline.scala:36)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.super$startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.$anonfun$startLoop$1(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
    at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.execute(Trampoline.scala:43)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC.execute(TrampolineEC.scala:44)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:72)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:52)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:136)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.signal(IORunLoop.scala:355)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:376)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:316)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOShift$Tick.run(IOShift.scala:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that the key type in `ConsumerSettings[IO, String, String]` is `String` but embedded-kafka writes `Null` as a key, so on deserializing the key it fails with NullPointerException. Setting key type to `Unit` solves the problem with exception.

Another problem is that `withRunningKafkaOnFoundPort` finished before the evaluation of the IO starts. To have it running it is needed to make a `Resource` from embedded-kafka and wrap the IO into that.

```scala
val embeddedKafka = Resource.make(IO(EmbeddedKafka.start()))((kafka) => IO(kafka.stop(true)))
```

Next problem is that `fs2-kafka` cannot work with a single thread executor so you have to provide it with an executor pool (for example `ExecutionContext.global`).

Here is a full working example:

```
import cats.effect._
import fs2.Stream
import fs2.kafka.{AutoOffsetReset, ConsumerSettings, consumerStream}
import net.manub.embeddedkafka.{EmbeddedKafka, EmbeddedKafkaConfig}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class KafkaSuite extends FunSuite with EmbeddedKafka {

  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
  implicit val contextShift = IO.contextShift(ec)
  implicit val timer = IO.timer(ec)

  val topic = "example"
  val partition = 0
  val clientId = "client"
  val userDefinedConfig = EmbeddedKafkaConfig(kafkaPort = 0, zooKeeperPort = 0)

  def broker(port: Long) = s"localhost:${port}"

  val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings[IO, Unit, String]
    .withAutoOffsetReset(AutoOffsetReset.Earliest)
    .withEnableAutoCommit(true)
    .withGroupId("group")
    .withClientId(clientId)

  val embeddedKafka = Resource.make(IO(EmbeddedKafka.start()))((kafka) => IO(kafka.stop(true)))

  test("works") {
    val r = Stream.resource(embeddedKafka).flatMap { kafka =>
      implicit val actualConfig: EmbeddedKafkaConfig = kafka.config
      createCustomTopic(topic)
      publishStringMessageToKafka(topic, "example-message1")
      publishStringMessageToKafka(topic, "example-message2")
      publishStringMessageToKafka(topic, "example-message3")
      publishStringMessageToKafka(topic, "example-message4")

      consumerStream(consumerSettings.withBootstrapServers(broker(actualConfig.kafkaPort)))
        .evalTap(_.subscribeTo(topic))
        .evalTap(_.seekToBeginning)
        .flatMap(_.stream)
        .map(_.record.value)
        .take(1)
    }
    val res = r.compile.toList.unsafeRunSync()
    assert(res.contains("example-message1"))
  }

}
```